# CPU Consumption of apache spark process

Tags: apache-spark, cpu-usage

I have a system with 6 physical cores and each core has 8 hardware threads resulting in 48 virtual cores. Following are the setting in configuration files.

**spark-env.sh**

export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1

**spark-defaults.conf**

spark.driver.cores 1

spark.executor.cores 1

spark.cores.max 1

So it means it should only use 1 virtual core but if we see the output from the TOP command, some time, it has very huge spikes e.g the CPU consumption is above 4000 e.g.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 22581 sbaig     20   0  0.278t 0.064t  37312 S  4728  6.4   7:11.30 java
....
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 22581 sbaig     20   0  0.278t 0.065t  37312 S  1502  6.5   8:22.75 java
...
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 22581 sbaig     20   0  0.278t 0.065t  37312 S  4035  6.6   9:51.64 java
...
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 22581 sbaig     20   0  0.278t 0.080t  37312 S  3445  8.1  15:06.26 java
...
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 22581 sbaig     20   0  0.278t 0.082t  37312 S  4178  8.2  17:37.59 java
...
```

It means, instead of using 1 virtual core, spark is using all available cores in the system so my question is why it is behaving like this? why it is not using only 1 core during execution of job which we set in SPARK_WORKER_CORES property.

I am using spark 1.6.1 with standalone mode.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
Shuja

Comment: Did you find a solution for the same, i have exactly the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

As the per the information you provided, it looks like you are setting the information in spark-defaults.conf file only.

In order to apply this configuration in your spark application, you have to configure these three properties in **`SparkConf`** object of code while creating the spark context as shown below.

```
var conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.cores","1")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores","1")
conf.set("spark.cores.max","1")
```

Or if you are submitting the application using the **`spark-submit CLI`** then you can use the **`--driver-cores`**, **`--executor-cores`** and **`--conf spark.cores.max=1`** options while running application.

Comment: if you are mentioning in spark-defaults.conf then there is no need to repeat these properties anywhere else.  The setting you describing here, is used when you want to override the default properties. Hope I made it clear to you.